# how to delete tableview cell from parse's server and local storage

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, swift2

```
  import UIKit

class MasterTableViewController: UITableViewController, PFLogInViewControllerDelegate, PFSignUpViewControllerDelegate {


 // creating array for holding ojects 



var noteObjects: NSMutableArray! = NSMutableArray()
  var v = 0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)



    if v == 0 {
        self.fetchAllObjectsFromLocalDataStore()
        //self.fetchAllObjects()


    }
}


// fetching data from local datastrore and from parse

func fetchAllObjectsFromLocalDataStore(){

    let query: PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "classname")
    query.orderByDescending("createdAt")

    query.fromLocalDatastore()

    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in

        if (error == nil) {




            let temp: NSArray = objects as! NSArray

            self.noteObjects = temp.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableArray

             self.tableView.reloadData()

        }else {
        print(error!.userInfo)

        }
    }

}


func fetchAllObjects(){

   let query: PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "classname")
    query.orderByDescending("createdAt")

    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in

        if (error == nil) {




            PFObject.pinAllInBackground(objects, block:  nil )


            self.fetchAllObjectsFromLocalDataStore()

           // self.tableView.reloadData()


        } else {
        print(error?.userInfo)

        }
 }
}





override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return self.noteObjects.count
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MasterTableViewCell

 let object : PFObject = self.noteObjects.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! PFObject


    cell.MasterTitleLabel?.text = object["Title"] as? String
    cell.MasterTextLabel.text = object["Fstory"] as? String
    cell.MasterTimeLabel.text = object["Time"] as? String
    cell.MasterLocationLabel.text = object["Location"] as? String

    return cell
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("openStory", sender: self)

}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    let upcoming: AddNoteTableViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! AddNoteTableViewController

    if (segue.identifier == "openStory"){


        let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!

        let object: PFObject = self.noteObjects.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! PFObject

        upcoming.object = object

        self.tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
}

}


@IBAction func btnReload(sender: AnyObject) {

    fetchAllObjects()


}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete){


        noteObjects.removeObjectAtIndex(indexPath.row)
        self.tableView.reloadData()

  }
}
}
```

the above code is for retrieving objects with are saved in Parse's server am able to retrieve the data and store it on my local data storage too but i don't know how to delete the selected cell from my tableview when am deleting it from the commitEditing.delete..... command it keep sending me object which is in my local storage so please if somebody knows how to do that deleting thing than explain me with codes thanks have a good day :)

Comment: Why aren't you calling delete on the note object before you remove it from the array?

Comment: literally have no idea i read through the documentation too but didn't get any thing from there , am a noob in iOS development , can you tell me how to that ?

Comment: you're mean this command ? @Wain noteObjects.delete(<#T##sender: AnyObject?##AnyObject?#>)

Comment: This is nothing to do with iOS really, it's looking at the API for PFObject to see what it offers. It doesn't take any parameters. You're trying to call delete on the array there, not on the note in the array

Comment: okay @Wain what i need to do for deleting them from local storage and from parse's server ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the object from the array and call delete on it before you remove it from the array:

```
let object : PFObject = self.noteObjects.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! PFObject
object.deleteInBackground()
```

Comment: hey man @Wain did anybody told you how awesome person is you are ! thanks a lot man trying to figure this out from last 7 hours you really helped me thanks a lot i really appreciate this